# Pandoc: Syntax package causes error "Missing endcsname inserted"

Tags: latex, grammar, pandoc, bnf

I'm using Pandoc to write a report, and I want to use the syntax package to typeset a BNF grammar.

What I tried was to `\usepackage{syntax}` in the `header-includes` of the Pandoc metadata yaml at the top of my document. Then I write my grammar like so within the document body:

```
\begin{grammar}

<statement> ::= <ident> `=' <expr> 
\alt `for' <ident> `=' <expr> `to' <expr> `do' <statement> 
\alt `{' <stat-list> `}' 
\alt <empty> 

<stat-list> ::= <statement> `;' <stat-list> | <statement> 

\end{grammar}
```

(Example from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24886/which-package-can-be-used-to-write-bnf-grammars))

And when I run pandoc in the terminal to compile my document, I get this error message:

```
Error producing PDF.
! Missing endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   protect
l.371 ...4949db3940f9f3a99133c3bbd69af2cf3fcd.png}
```

What is even more strange is that I get this error even if I just `\usepackage{syntax}` without even writing a grammar. A search for the package on my computer using `kpsewhich syntax.sty` in the terminal shows that it is indeed installed. I've seen someone else talk about a similar issue online, where the problem was that their document was referencing files which had underscores in their names, but I do not have any filenames with underscores in them.

Comment: Can you make a [mre] and show the intermediate .tex file?

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely caused by using underscore in your labels. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/427619/164543) has the solution, but the error message there is different. I had the error message that is asked here and `\usepackage[nounderscore]{syntax}` solved it for me.